# EnhanceList to override a Tab

Tags: visualforce

I have a requirement in which I had to override the Tab of a Custom Object(say My_CustomObject__c)

Using enhancedlist I have overridden the tab as:

```
<apex:page tabStyle="My_CustomObject__c">
 <apex:enhancedList  type="My_CustomObject__c" height="600" rowsPerPage="50" id="ObjID" customizable="true" />
</apex:page>
```

Now when visit the tab, Edit button of that list is not working. Am I missing something in enhancedlist attribute? And on click of that Custom Object ID page is not redirecting to the detail page of the record. 
But if I am Opening in New Tab both "Edit" and Detail Page of that record is working fine.

Please help me to fix this issue in EnahncedList.

Comment: I got it, Instead of using an enhacedlist, I used

<apex:page showHeader="true" tabstyle="Account">
    <apex:ListViews type="Account" />
</apex:page>  
and it worked. But its like a related list view, Can I have List view of the Object without New Button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got what I was searching for

```
<apex:page action="{!URLFOR($Action.User_Configuration__c.List, $ObjectType.User_Configuration__c)}"/>
```